# Per user password of a sql ce database

Tags: sql-server-ce

Is there anyway to password protect a sqlce database, per user?
Say I have two users, Mary and Sally. Mary can only access her info and vis versa. 
Or would I have to duplicate the database for each user and give each instance it's own password.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, SQL CE doesn't support any concept of users.